# Amazon Cognito with iOS: Access to Identity Forbidden

Tags: ios, swift, amazon-cognito

Thanks for the help in advance!

I am having some trouble getting Amazon Cognito to store/synchronize data properly.

On the dataset.synchronize() line (which does not store the data in Cognito), I get a large output error (with ID starred out) such as:

```
AWSCredentialsProvider.m line:429 | __73-[AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider 
getCredentialsWithCognito:authenticated:]_block_invoke |   GetCredentialsForIdentity
failed. Error is [Error Domain=com.amazonaws.AWSCognitoIdentityErrorDomain 
Code=10 "(null)" UserInfo={__type=NotAuthorizedException, message=Access to
Identity '*****' is forbidden.}]
```

The cognitoID is not nil, and returns properly (and matches the values I can read online)

For instance, after authenticating with Facebook, I perform the following:

```
  if (FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken() != nil)
    {
        let fbCognitoToken = FBSDKAccessToken.currentAccessToken().tokenString
        credentialsProvider.logins = [AWSCognitoLoginProviderKey.Facebook.rawValue: fbCognitoToken]
        // Retrieve your Amazon Cognito ID
        credentialsProvider.getIdentityId().continueWithBlock { (task: AWSTask!) -> AnyObject! in
            if (task.error != nil) {
                print("Error: " + task.error!.localizedDescription)
            }
            else {
                // the task result will contain the identity id
                let cognitoId = task.result

                //checking if cognito was successful, if true, sets success condition to true to prepare for segue into app
                if cognitoId != nil{
                    print (cognitoId)
                    cognitoSuccess = true

                    let syncClient = AWSCognito.defaultCognito()

                    let dataset = syncClient.openOrCreateDataset("User_Data")
                    dataset.setString("test@test.com", forKey:"Email")
                //    credentialsProvider.refresh()
                    dataset.synchronize()
                    } }return nil}}
```

I can read data from Facebook correctly, and all authentication occurred correctly from what I can tell. I suspect there is something simple that is at the root here, but after spending several days, I cannot figure it out! Using the IAM checker in the AWS portal returns all "green checks" for Cognito functions, so I am sure this not a permissions issue on the server-side, either.

Thanks again for any insight you might have!

Edit:
Before the chunk of code above, I call:

```
let credentialsProvider = self.initializeCognito()
```

which runs (identity pool ID starred out):

```
 func initializeCognito () -> AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider
{
    let credentialsProvider = AWSCognitoCredentialsProvider(
        regionType: AWSRegionType.USEast1, identityPoolId: "******")

    let defaultServiceConfiguration = AWSServiceConfiguration(
        region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

    AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = defaultServiceConfiguration

    return credentialsProvider     
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out the answer-- when I first set up AWS and was following some of Amazon's guides, I had placed code to create a new credentialsProvider in the application's App Delegate. I forgot about it, and then was trying later on to initialize another credentialsProvider. This confusion created the issues, and removing the initialization in App Delegate fixed the authentication problems.

Answer (score 0):

That exception can be thrown when you're trying to get credentials for an authenticated id without giving any provider token linked to it. Cognito requires at least one to be given.

Can you check that you're including the facebook token during the GetCredentialsForIdentity call that's failing? If not, I'd guess that's your issue.

Edit:

Since you are using AWSCognito.defaultCognito(), it might help to follow the example on [this docs page](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/cognito/latest/developerguide/step1-getting-started.html) to make sure the sync client uses the right credentials provider:

```
let configuration = AWSServiceConfiguration(region: AWSRegionType.USEast1, credentialsProvider: credentialsProvider)

AWSServiceManager.defaultServiceManager().defaultServiceConfiguration = configuration
```

Comment: Thanks for the response! In the 4th line of code as shown above, I do pass the Facebook token to the cognito credentials provider-- is this insufficient? If I might ask, what should I have written? Thanks!

Comment: That depends a bit. Is it failing immediately after you try logging in? Or are you closing the app and waiting a bit? If the former, are you initializing the sync client with this credentials provider?

Comment: After login to Facebook (which is successful), this code is immediately called. cognitoID returns "correctly" i.e. when I have it print (cognitoID) to make sure I'm not getting nil or something nonsensical, a unique identifier (equal to the one I can find the AWS Cognito Identity Browser) is correctly printed. I had commented out the credentialsProvider.refresh() line, but putting that in just returns another error similar to the one already provided for the .synchronise() line. So in short, no, there is no close/reopening going on!

Comment: Apologies, I'm no iOS expert and was pretty unclear on my second question. Can you give my edit a try and see what happens?

Comment: Thank you so much for giving it a shot-- I tried to place this statement before syncClient = AWSCognito.defaultCognito() , but that did not help-- I pretty much already have that code in there! See edits to my original question: I realize I should have provided more information when asking the first time-- my apologies.

Comment: Your code snippet looks fine to me. Can you try calling clearKeyChain on the credentials provider? I just noticed your comment on refresh throwing the same error - it sounds like what might have happened is the SDK has the login for a previous user cached and it's clashing.

Comment: I tried, and I tried calling it in many places-- nothing has changed, unfortunately. I have only been trying to login with my personal Facebook account, so I doubt there'd be a conflict of user information anyways. Thank you so much for trying to help with this issue-- it's definitely bizarre!